recommendation engine for frequently bought products
I have the Sales billed data to a customer, where i want to develop a recommendation engine which will recommend the product purchased with minimum frequency of 8 times and the quantity of those products. I have approx. 1.5 year of data in excel format. Suggest the steps & methods to follow to analyze the data.
I want the forecast data of the product data weekly so that it will help me in pushing to the customers on the weekly basis.
